# How to get View in SimpleOnGestureListener

Tags: android

I have a class:

```
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {


    @Override

    public void  onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
   //Do something
    }
 }
```

How can I get View of wiget, which was longpressed (in my case it's Item in Listview).

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnItemLongClickListener` instead.

Comment: I'd like to use SingleTap, DoubleTap and LongTap at the same 'listview'. So I guess only 'SimpleOnGestureListener' can do it.

Comment: Just set both listeners. The on OnItemClickListener will only be called when you lift your finger quickly.